# No cached version of org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.3.71

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle, react-native, android-studio-3.6

all are lastest version...

There are errors after I updated android studio 3.6.3, updated gradle and npm install react-native-swiper...

[android studio errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ofk7X.png)

I try to solve, bug my as settings have not offline work checkbox, please click picture to view

[android studio settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gbJir.png)

kotlin plug versions is 1.3.72, bug it show 1.3.71 in errors

[kotlin 1.3.72 had downloaded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zd0Qp.png)

why!!!

Comment: you are offline mode. set Online mode.Restart ide and do gradle

Answer (score 3, accepted):

from Android Studio 3.6, there is a new location to toggle Gradle's offline mode:

> To enable or disable Gradle's offline mode, first select View > Tool Windows > Gradle from the menu bar. Then, near the top of the Gradle window, click Toggle Offline Mode Gradle offline button in the Gradle panel..

Toggle button looks like this [image]

[source](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/#3.6-gradle-offline-ui)